# How to change the validation message of required in Angular Validators

Tags: angular

Is there a way to change the validation message of FormBuilder in Angular? I have this code below that gives the 'red' word 'wrong' whenever the input field is left blank. The validator works but I just want to change it to something more meaningful like "This field is required".

```
<form [formGroup]="subscriptionForm">
    <h3 style="color: gray; text-align: center;">Registration</h3>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="text" formControlName="UserName" id="UserName" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
            <label for="UserName">Your UserName</label>
            <div *ngIf="subscriptionForm.get('UserName').hasError('required')">
                This field is required!
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="text" formControlName="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
            <label for="FirstName">Your First name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-indigo btn-lg btn-block waves-light" type="button" (click)="onSubmit()"  [disabled]="!subscriptionForm.valid" mdbWavesEffect>Send
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    </div>

</form>

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptionForm = this.fb.group({
        UserName: [null, Validators.required],
        FirstName: [null, Validators.required]
    });
}
```

If you will notice I tried creating an *ngIf but somehow, it doesn't work. However, I would like it better if I do not have to create this *ngIf but if there is really no way to do it, then *ngIf is fine. Can you please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: The Angular docs show to use a syntax like `name.errors.required` in your `*ngIf`, where `name` in your case looks like it would be `UserName`. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
<div *ngIf="subscriptionForm.get('UserName').errors.required">
            This field is required!
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello @miran-parkar, IMO this is not a good way to deal with a long term problem. [I opened an issue in the Angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46405). Please contribute in it

Answer (score 0):

```
<app-form-group-control-validation-display  [formGroup]="subscriptionForm" [propertyName]="'UserName'" [custom]="[{'required':'This field is required !'}]">
                        </app-form-group-control-validation-display>
```